# how can validate website address in android application

Tags: android

i am developing android application website address how can implemented validation

example :  www.yahoo.com

please forward some solution

Comment: What language are you writing the program in?

Comment: Wat do you mean by `validate` website address?

Comment: in java programing  validation website address 
i am implementing email address is working fine 
^[A-Za-z0-9._%+\\-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.\\-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$ this validation implementing   
website validation how can implemented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have expanded a little bit on what you said, your question was very confusing, you should have also mention you were using regex.

Try this:

`^[A-Za-z0-9.\\-]+.[A-Za-z0-9.\\-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$`

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you want to check if a website exists

You could try this, make sure the android.INTERNET permission is selected in your manifest.

```
 String host = "http://www.yahoo.com/";
 int timeOut = 3000; // I recommend 3 seconds at least
 boolean status = InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeOut);
```

Comment: sorry this solution is not use my application   in java website validation then above code